# SSH to port exposed by container - permission denied

Tags: c++, docker, ssh

I have a docker container running and it's exposing port 22 to local host port 1312. I am using the following command to run the container:

> docker run -it -d -p 127.0.0.1:1312:22 -v
> /workspace/project:/root --name
> cpp_dep cpp_dep

Now to build the project in CLion, it need to be able to ssh into the container. I entered the container in interactive mode and ran "service ssh restart".

Now when I try to ssh into root@127.0.0.1:1312, it asks for my password. But when I enter my sudo (root) password, it keeps saying permission denied.

Is it an issue with ssh key? Which password should i use? or is there any way to bypass the password?

I am running a MAC OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in the image's Dockerfile?  What's the main container process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may enter the container in interactive mode, use `whoami` to find the current user while use `passwd` to change the password of current user, then ssh into it using the updated passwd.

More details if you are interested:

User running the container is decided by

- `USER` config in your `Dockerfile`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user
- `-u` option in `docker run` command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

By default it's root (uid = 0), but it depends on your settings.

User password is stored in `/etc/passwd` file, which is different inside the container and in the host, so the same uid may have different password inside the container. It's a workaround to mannually reset it using `passwd` in the interactive mode but your may also set it in `Dockerfile` like

```
RUN echo 'root:Docker!' | chpasswd  // (NOTICE: unsafe!)
```

It changes the password for `root` as "Docker!"

**EDIT #1**

As emphasized by David Maze in comments, it's **unsafe** to store plain password in the Dockerfile as it's public to anyone who get the source file, and it's not uncommon source files intended to be private mistakenly submitted to open github repository. If the container needs to provide public service, you **must** use build args (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) so password can be secretly specified at build time.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG PASSWD
RUN echo 'root:${PASSWD}' | chpasswd
```

build:

```
docker build --build-arg PASSWD=<secret stored safely>
```

Comment: Writing a clear-text root password in a file that will be committed to source control or easily retrieved via `docker history` really isn't a best practice.

Comment: As i don't need to commit by dockerfile, this solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your advice, I agree that we must emphasize explicitly that unsafe workaround is unsafe. I edit my answer and add a solution using Docker build args.